# Javascript function call in Handlebar

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I am trying to use a javascript function call that creates a d3 pie chart in handlebars template.

Here is my script:-

```
<style>
#name {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    width: 34%;
}

#group {
    color: red;
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
}

#wave {
    color: green;
    float: left;
    width: 33%
}



#chart {
    width: 350px;
    padding: 10px;
}

#footer {
    color: blue;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}


#header {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<div id="test"></div>

<script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
{{#each this}}

<div id="header">
        <div id="wave" style="color: #000FFF; font-size: 28px">Wave</div>
        <div id="name" style="color: #000000; font-size: 28px">{{name}}</div>
        <div id="group" style="color: #000000; font-size: 28px">{{groupName}}</div>
 </div>


<div id="table">
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="chart">{{recommendedFoods 25 25 25 25}}</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Questions? Contact us 
</div>
{{/each}}
</script>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.7.0/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/2.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function (){
     Handlebars.registerHelper("recommendedFoods", function(a,b,c,d) {
            var w = 200;
            var h = 200;
            var r = h / 2;
            d3.select("#chart").append("text").attr("text-anchor", "middle").style(
                    "font-size", "28px").style("text-decoration", "bold").text(
                    "Recommended");
            var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(
                    [ "#ffe5ff", "#ffeee5", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00" ]);
            //GPVF
            var data = [ {
                "label" : "8",
                "value" : a
            }, {
                "label" : "3",
                "value" : b
            }, {
                "label" : "6",
                "value" : c
            }, {
                "label" : "2",
                "value" : d
            } ];

            var vis = d3.select('#chart').append("svg:svg").data([ data ]).attr(
                    "width", w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform",
                    "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
            var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
                return d.value;
            });

            // declare an arc generator function
            var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

            // select paths, use arc generator to draw
            var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g")
                    .attr("class", "slice");

            arcs.append("svg:path").attr("fill", function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
                // return color(d.data.value)
            }).attr("d", function(d) {
                console.log(arc(d));
                return arc(d);
            }).attr('stroke', '#fff') // <-- THIS
            .attr('stroke-width', '3');

            // add the text
            arcs.append("svg:text").attr("transform", function(d) {
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = r;
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
            }).attr("text-anchor", "middle").text(function(d, i) {
                return data[i].label;
            });
        //}
        return this;
        });

     var source = $("#template").html();
     var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var string = [{"groupName":"Default Group","name":"Dummy"},{"groupName":"New","name":"Becker"}];
    var ht = template(string);
    $("#test").html(ht);


});

</script>
```

The recommendedFoods function is being executed properly if I call it in the script without using it in the template.
But , I am trying to `return this` in the function `recommendedFood` and I do not see anything being displayed on the output. 
Can anyone please help me fix this.
What should be returned from the function so that it can be displayed using the handlebars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because by the time you call Handlebars helper there is no `#chart` element in the DOM yet.

So you need to:

1. change `#chart` to class `.chart` because you will have multiple elements
2. build your charts after Handlebars executes.
3. store values for your charts e.g. in the same `strings` object where you already have some relevant info.

Checkout demo - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ermakovnikolay/ezk4neL2/).

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var source = $("#template").html();
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var string = [{
        "groupName": "Default Group",
        "name": "Dummy",
        "values": [25, 25, 25, 25]
    }, {
        "groupName": "New",
        "name": "Becker",
        "values": [10, 5, 25, 25]
    }];
    var ht = template(string);
    $("#test").html(ht);

    $('.chart').each(function(index, el) {

        var w = 200;
        var h = 200;
        var r = h / 2;
        d3.select(el).append("text").attr("text-anchor", "middle").style(
            "font-size", "28px").style("text-decoration", "bold").text(
            "Recommended");
        var color = d3.scale.ordinal().range(
            ["#ffe5ff", "#ffeee5", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]);
        //GPVF
        var data = [{
            "label": "8",
            "value": string[index].values[0]
        }, {
            "label": "3",
            "value": string[index].values[1]
        }, {
            "label": "6",
            "value": string[index].values[2]
        }, {
            "label": "2",
            "value": string[index].values[3]
        }];

        var vis = d3.select(el).append("svg:svg").data([data]).attr(
            "width", w).attr("height", h).append("svg:g").attr("transform",
            "translate(" + r + "," + r + ")");
        var pie = d3.layout.pie().value(function(d) {
            return d.value;
        });

        // declare an arc generator function
        var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(r);

        // select paths, use arc generator to draw
        var arcs = vis.selectAll("g.slice").data(pie).enter().append("svg:g").attr("class", "slice");

        arcs.append("svg:path").attr({
            "fill": function(d, i) {
                return color(i);
            },
            "d": function(d) {
                console.log(arc(d));
                return arc(d);
            },
            'stroke': '#fff',
            'stroke-width': '3'
        });

        // add the text
        arcs.append("svg:text").attr({
            "transform": function(d) {
                d.innerRadius = 0;
                d.outerRadius = r;
                return "translate(" + arc.centroid(d) + ")";
            },
            "text-anchor": "middle"
        }).text(function(d, i) {
            return data[i].label;
        });

    });

})
```

Comment: Can I not do this using a handlebar helper function be returning some object and passing it to the template?

Comment: It is what handlebars is all about - passing the object with properties and fill out the template html markup with values from those properties. Only the new elements that are described in the template will be added to the DOM when handlebar finishes execution. You cannot refer future elements inside the helper that actually builds them. So you cannot call `d3.select(element)` on element that is not there yet. Why you don't want to use `jQuery. ready` ?